# Site Crashed After Back Up. How do I change the php to "664"

Tags: backup

I have finished my site and thought I should back it up. What a disaster the site is now completely blank and I cant access the admin area either http://www.cellar2door.com

I know that there are lots of similar posts and the answers all seem to point to changing the php to 664.

However, I am a real noobie and have no idea where I do this. Can someone point me in the right direction so i can try and fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you search, you will get the answer, like check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt). 
Most accepted answer of "WombleGoneBad" states:

To change **all the directories to 755** (-rwxr-xr-x):

```
find [enter your path of root directory] -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

To change **all the files to 644** (-rw-r--r--):

```
find [enter your path of root directory] -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks MTM. I had found that answer. But as mentioned I am really really new at this. Where do I actually look for find (my root directory) is this in the file manager?

Comment: which Operating system are you using?

Comment: if you have access to file manager, you can navigate to the folder where magento is installed, and then copy the directory path. It might be `/var/www/html/` or may be `/public_html/htdocs` etc, check yours.

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9. If i go in my file manager and look for where Magento is it is in public_html/lib/Magento

Comment: if you are sure, you can use the path `/public_html/lib/Magento/` in the above code, but be sure about the path, do u see app, var,js, media etc folders there?

Comment: sorry for not fully undertsanding. under public_html I have  
 
app
 
downloader
 
errors
 
includes
 
js
 
lib
 
media
 
pkginfo
 
shell
 
skin
 
sql
 
var

Comment: then your root directory path is '/public_html/'

Comment: sorry MTM it is telling me not to have long discussions here and I am so new I cannot use the chat facility yet. Ok so I know the path or root directory but don't get what to do next. Sorry

Comment: Thanks MTM for trying to help. Sometimes it its difficult when you are really new to all of this to get ones head around it. Anyway happy to report that I reached out to bluehost my hosting company and they fixed it for me so will be able to sleep well tonight